# ngOnInit is calling before resolver data is ready

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-resolver

I have a resolve that is calling getSchools() from service

### resolver.ts

```
export abstract class APIResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
          constructor(readonly dropdownService:DropDownOptionsService,readonly route:ActivatedRoute) { }
          abstract resolve();
        }


export class APISchoolsresolve extends APIResolverService{

      resolve(){
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
          let district = params['district'];
          return this.dropdownService.getSchools(district);   
        })
      }
```

### My Service

```
async getSchools(districtID:number){
    return await this.http.get<ISchool[]>(`api/GetSchools/` + districtID).toPromise();
  }
```

### My Component

```
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data) =>{

      console.log(data);
    })
```

my data in component is undefined as it is being called before my resolver get data.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resolve method doesn't return anything. So the router doesn't wait for anything to be resolved: what could it possibly subscribe to or await for?

Also, the resolve method takes an `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`. That's where you should take the districtID from.

Here's what the resolver should look like:

```
export class APISchoolsresolve implements Resolve<Array<ISchool>> {
  constructor(private dropdownService: DropdownService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<Array<ISchool>> {
    return this.dropdownService.getSchools(+route.paramMap.get('district'));
  }
}
```